# Compiled with problems SASS

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, sass

i got some compilation problem when i start my App :

```
Compiled with problems:
```

> ERROR in ./src/styles/pages/_Home.scss
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ePj.png).rules[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ePj.png).oneOf[7].use[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ePj.png)!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ePj.png).rules[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ePj.png).oneOf[7].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ePj.png).rules[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ePj.png).oneOf[7].use[3]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ePj.png).rules[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2ePj.png).oneOf[7].use[4]!./src/styles/pages/_Home.scss)
> 5:36-87
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../src/images/bg.png' in
> 'C:\Users\joucy\Desktop\joucep\src\styles\pages'

all the path are ok but still have this message as you can see on the screenshot, can someone help me ? maybe i'm doing something wrong
[image]
my Home.jsx look like :

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/pages/_Home.scss'
import '../images/bg.png';


const Home = () => {
    
    return (
        
        <div className="main-container">
            
        </div>
        
    );
    
};

export default Home;
```

Comment: can you show package.json file

Answer (score 0):

configure support for PNG-image for webpack 4 file-loader

install the file loader

```
npm install --save-dev file-loader
```

change `webpack.config.js` to have the following rules

```js
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.png$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
```

you can find more info to support other file types [here](https://blog.jakoblind.no/webpack-file-loader/)